# In android way to differentiate Activity:onUserInteractions

Tags: android

Android Activity defines `onUserInteraction` Api but fails to define what type of interaction it is. The question specifically came because there is no way to check if the User Interaction is been caused due to any keyEvent or due to user leaving from it.

Comment: Based on semantics the user leaving is not an interaction, its quite the opposite. Also you have a method for user leaving: onUserLeaveHint();

Answer (score 0):

### **`onUsernteraction()`**

Based on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onuserinteraction) for `onUsernteraction()` :

> Called whenever a **key, touch, or trackball event is dispatched to the activity**. Implement this method if you wish to know that the user has interacted with the device in some way while your activity is running.

It indicates that this call back will be called whenever key, touch or trackball event is dispatched.

**Note:**

> This callback will be invoked for the touch down action that begins a touch gesture, but may not be invoked for the touch-moved and touch-up actions that follow.

### **`onUserLeaveHint()`**

If your intention is to detect user leaving from an Activity, then you can use `onUserLeaveHint()` callback. Based on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onUserLeaveHint()) for `onUserLeaveHint()`:

> **Called as part of the activity lifecycle when an activity is about to go into the background** as the result of user choice. For example, when the user presses the Home key, onUserLeaveHint() will be called,

**Note:**

> When an incoming phone call causes the in-call Activity to be
>   automatically brought to the foreground, onUserLeaveHint() will not be
>   called on the activity being interrupted. In cases when it is invoked,
>   this method is called right before the activity's onPause() callback.

`onUserLeaveHint()` & `onUsernteraction()` are mainly intended to help activities manage status bar notifications intelligently; specifically, for helping activities determine the proper time to cancel a notification.